# Which things will change between playthroughs of the same level?

Tags: monaco

I've noticed that the wall outlets (the things hackers can use to get a virus) are at different places every time a level is started. This got me wondering, what other things can be different between playthroughs? Placement of coins, guards, objectives, animals and keys? Paths of guards and civilians? Times when telephones ring?

Also, is it possible to enter some kind of seed so you play the exact same level again?